# Can we derive spin of particle somehow?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

so my quantum mechanics teacher told me that spin is just a intrinsic quantity that we just need to accept .But my question is that can we somehow derive the spin of a particle like for example adding a extra energy(spin energy) term to the Schrödinger equation(and somehow getting a spin quantum number from applying some sort of boundary condition) or maybe in any other way(maybe some more advanced theory which i haven't read yet).

Comment: You mean deriving the Dirac equation?

Comment: Can the dirac equation gives us the value of spin directly?

Comment: Yes, it implies spin 1/2.

Comment: Alternative for non-relativistic quantum mechanics, you can take a look at the derivation of Levy-Leblond equation (which is equivalent to Pauli equation and follows the same method as Dirac equation)